# How do I convert int values to hh:mm in C#?

Tags: c#, datetime, type-conversion, datetime-format, timespan

I want to convert the int value `600` to `06:00` and `1700` to `17:00` in C#.

This is what I have tried so far:

```
int val = 600;
TimeSpan result = TimeSpan.FromHours(val);
string fromTimeString = result.ToString("hh':'mm");
```

How can this be achieved?

Comment: Welcome to SO. You might want to look at the (docs)[https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/standard/base-types/formatting-types?view=netframework-4.8]. Also, for future reference, please provide what exactly you got wrong in order to promptly receive an adequate answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you have only hours and minutes you can create the `TimeSpan` like this:

```
// Assuming val is always valid:
TimeSpan result = new TimeSpan(val / 100, val % 100, 0);
```